# Kill all delayed_job workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, delayed-job

I use delayed_job as a daemon https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job/wiki/Running-Delayed::Worker-as-a-daemon

I can't tell why, but sometimes I see more than one job done by several workers (different pids), and running `stop` doesn't stop anything. is there a way to kill all daemons of this proc/all workers? Or kill a specific pid (I'm on a shared hosting so kill/killall aren't available for me).

Answer (score 1):

Not having access to "kill" in this setup will quickly become a PITA, and it boggles my mind that you wouldn't have the ability to kill processes you yourself started.

For increased worker dependability, you might want to try the collectiveidea fork of delayed_job, and using the daemon-spawn gem rather than daemons.  I've had better luck with that combination.

Comment: Thanks. I just don't get it - how can I start a process and not stop it without a kill? Maybe I should look at Daemons spec.
I'll also check collectiveidea's fork.

Comment: OK. I saw in the logs that it was Memory exception. So i realized shared hosting is not for me. Moved to VPS and it works great!

Comment: The collectiveidea fork is the way to go.

Comment: I also had better luck with daemon-spawn